# Simple html parsing with php

Tags: php, html

Hi i am using simple_html_dom library to parse this html

```
<tr class="even">
<th>Yesterday</th>
<td class="avg">42.57%</td>
<td class="percent"> -0.06% </td>
<td class='arrow'> </td>
</tr>
<tr >
<th>7 day</th>
<td class="avg">41.79%</td>
<td class="percent"> +0.14% </td>
<td class='arrow'> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<th>1 month</th>
<td class="avg">42.10%</td>
<td class="percent"> -5.63% </td>
<td class='arrow'> </td>
</tr>
<tr >
<th>3 month</th>
<td class="avg">44.198%</td>
<td class="percent"> -2.28% </td>
<td class='arrow'> </td>
</tr>
```

I need all data in separate variables. such as Average etc... Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you post what you already have ?

Comment: Please provide more info. Do you want only one output number for each category? What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: yes i need numbers only for all tr

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to crawl through them as such:

```
<?php
    $simpleHTMLDom = new simple_html_dom();
    $simpleHTMLDom->load($html);
    $tableRows = $simpleHTMLDom->find('tr');

    $rows = array();
    if (!empty($tableRows)) {
        foreach ($tableRows as $tableRow) {
            $row = array();
            $tableColumns = $tableRow->find('td.avg, td.percent');
            if (!empty($tableColumns)) {
                foreach ($tableColumns as $tableColumn) {
                    $row[$tableColumn->class] = $tableColumn->innertext;
                }
            }
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    }
    print_r($rows);
?>
```

Comment: I'm very sorry. I totally read over OPs part of the question where he states he uses `simple_html_dom`. I blame the fact it is monday and my own stupidity

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 No worries - we've all been there done that. :-)